# How to install a shared library on Ubuntu Linux?

Tags: linux, ubuntu, installation

I'm having trouble shared libraries on my Ubuntu 10.04. I experienced it several times in the last months, read a lot about installing libs but I seem to miss the point.

Starting with the source code directory, I run the following commands:

> 1. `make`
>    Runs clean, without any error
> 2. `sudo make install`
>    Seems to be working fine, ends with:
>    cp foo.so.0.1 /usr/local/lib/
>    rm -f /usr/local/lib/foo.so
>    ln -s /usr/local/lib/foo.so.0.1 /usr/local/lib/foo.so
> 3. `sudo ldconfig`
>    Runs without any output

When writing a makefile, I can not address the lib by its name, but by its path:
Not working: `-lfoo`
Working: `-L/usr/local/lib/foo.so`

The problem stays the same, no matter what lib I try to install.

What am I missing here? Or what can I do to find out?

Comment: Boost in particular does not use automake or autoconf, so there is no scenario where you would run *those* commands... Have you read the [Boost Getting Started Guide](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_47_0/more/getting_started/unix-variants.html)?

Comment: boost can easily be added in Ubuntu by using `apt-get`, or your normal package manager.  Look for packages `libboost-dev`, or `libboost-all-dev`.  No need to install them manually unless you have a specific version that you have to link against that is different from the version provided by your repository.

Comment: I could not use the packet manager, because of an previously broken packet manager installation of boost and I needed it fast and yes, I read the getting started, but its long ago. boost just shold be an example, the other parts of the installation worked.

Comment: @user918545 : While the rest of the GNU/Linux world tends to use automake/autoconf, Boost does not. So Boost is **not** just an example, because it gets built by an entirely build system than everything else, and thus follows different build procedures.

Comment: Boost, nuts, forget it - should have been qt not boost. But I only mixed the installation procedures. The effect stays the same. I can not use boost libnames in my makefiles.

Answer (score 1):

Is `/usr/local/lib/` in your library search path? If not you will need to specify both `-lfoo` and `/usr/local/lib/` in your Makefile, so the linker knows where to look.

Whether or not `/usr/local/lib/` is in your library search path is dependent on your distribution.

Comment: Yes, (sadly) the usr/local/lib/ is in the search path. Other libs, installed bevore the problem occured first work how they are supposed to be working.

Answer (score 0):

Remember that the library names should start with `lib` and end with `.so`. Maybe you are missing the starting `lib`